# Get rows with timestamp from current week in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to build a weekly leaderboard of sorts and was wondering how I could get the rows with a timestamp that is within the current week (Monday to Sunday). I've tried:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) FROM Data WHERE created::date BETWEEN date $1 and date $2 GROUP BY id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 10;
```

But got stuck on how I could get the rows within the current week without hard coding them. `created` is a column of type `TIMESTAMP`.

I saw that there was something called `YEARWEEK()` in MySQL. Is there an equivalent in Postgres? If not, what can I do to get the desired result?

Comment: I'd be happy to clarify anything or provide more information should it prove necessary. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `date_trunc()` with "week":

```
where created >= date_trunc('week', now())
```

This assumes that no created timestamps are in the future.  Postgres follows the ISO standard of having weeks start on Mondays, which is what you want.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Postgres functions, but if NOW() is a Tuesday, would it still give me the results spanning from this week's Monday to Tuesday and not from Tuesday last week to this Tuesday? If that makes sense.

Comment: @Californium . . . Yes.  `date_trunc('week', now())` returns the most recent midnight between Sunday and Monday -- the beginning of the week.